# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Cache' not found /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php

Tags: class, zend-framework

Does anyone know why this kind of messages appear? It seems like my Magento installation does not fully load all Zend classes, although they are there on a proper place with proper file permissions.

If I try removing the whole project and uploading it again, it happens again, only with different Zend class.

Does anyone know how to debug these kind of errors?

---

SOLVED: by clearing the APC cache on the server. For whatever the reason, it loaded the old instance of Magento in cache and only partially the new ones, therefore causing the buggy behaviour.

Thanks once again to Alan and mbalparda for their responses.

Comment: Also if file permissions are off after an upgrade, and some of the files are not readable, Magento will throw this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by clearing the APC cache on the server. For whatever the reason, it loaded the old instance of Magento in cache and only partially the new ones, therefore causing the buggy behaviour.

Thanks once again to Alan and mbalparda for their responses.

Answer (score 3):

Magento's autoload should convert the class

```
Zend_Cache
```

into an include path of

```
Zend/Cache.php
```

and then look for that class in the following folders.

```
app/code/local/Zend/Cache.php
app/code/community/Zend/Cache.php
app/code/core/Zend/Cache.php
lib/Zend/Cache.php
```

In a standard install, it loads from `lib/Zend/Cache.php`.  So, the first thing I'd do is make sure the `lib/Zend/Cache.php` is there, and there is not a file at the other locations.  If there is a file at the other location(s), take a look inside and make sure a class named `Zend_Cache` is actually defined.

If the file's there, then it sounds like it's not being loaded correctly. The next debugging step I'd take is pinpointing the place in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php` where Magento's trying to use `Zend_Cache`, and make sure the PHP include paths have been setup correctly.  Use some `var_dump` debugging like this.

```
    #File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php
    var_dump(explode(':',get_include_path()));
    exit;
    $this->_frontend = Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Core', $backend['type'], $frontend, $backend['options'],
        true, true, true
    );
```

You should see output that looks something like this

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '/path/to/magento/app/code/local' (length=61)
  1 => string '/path/to/magento/app/code/community' (length=65)
  2 => string '/path/to/magento/app/code/core' (length=60)
  3 => string '/path/to/magento/lib' (length=50)
  4 => string '.' (length=1)
  5 => string '/usr/local/php5/lib/php' (length=23)
```

If `lib` and the code pools (`core`, `community`, `local`) aren't in there, it meant you may be dealing with a modified `app/Mage.php` file, or you may be running in Magento compiled mode without having compiled classes (doubtful in your case since the error comes from `app/code/core...`, but you never know)

Finally, if the paths were setup correctly, I'd look at the autoloader and add some debugging.

```
#File: lib/Varien/Autoload.php
var_dump($class);
var_dump($classFile);

return include $classFile;
```

Look for the path the autoloader tries to create for `Zend_Cache`, and then figure out why it can't load the class.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tnx mate for the response, I tried everything as you said and hit a dead end. Load paths are fine, files are there, file permissions are good.

I tried completely removing the shop and cloning it again from GIT, and now the same happens only with different class:

"Fatal error: Class 'Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found"

I'm thinking this could be something with the server configuration or memory limit or something.

Comment: @Relja I'm confused, you did everything I said — but you didn't mention which file path the autoloader displayed

Comment: It displayed exactly as you described, first 4 lines. I found out what was the problem, thanks once again for a detailed response.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your upload is failing and some files are missing.
Find an official Magento package with the version you are using, install it as a new installation with a separated db and set of files and once that is done, **merge (do not just overwrite)** everything from your site into the fresh installation.
This should fix the missing files.

Comment: Tnx, I already tried this - I have a GIT repo, I removed everything and cloned it again, and still it happens.

Comment: Im not sure you fully understand the difference. Repo might be broken, try putting the repo on top of a fresh and running Magento instance. By doing that you will be able to see first if any other instance of Magento works where you are installing it and if it does not, you will be sure the code is not the issue but probably the environment.

Comment: I think i saw this error somewhere else. Try the magento-check.php file (http://www.magentocommerce.com/_media/magento-check.zip) to see if the server meets the requirements. Also, as a lead, the codification/encoding of the files might be the issue. Im trying to justify the second lead but i cant find where i saw something like that

Comment: Thanks man, I found what was the problem, it was cache on the server level.